# Is there a way to make the Gingerbread notification behave like ICS?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, notifications

The ICS notification allows users to "swipe" single notifications away. I was wondering if this can be done on a rooted Gingerbread phone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a stock carrier/manufacturer's ROM there's probably not a whole lot you can do I would imagine, but [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/) 7 (its Gingerbread-based version) allows you to dismiss individual notifications by swiping them away. You can see it in action in [this Lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/5825474/clear-single-notifications-in-cyanogenmod-with-a-swipe-gesture).

Comment: Are there any 3rd party apps or mods that will allow me to do that on the Xperia GB rom?

Comment: @ShedoSurashu: I've never seen one (although that doesn't mean one does not exist somewhere). Re-working the notification bar's behavior is somewhat non-trivial, though, and AFAIK it's not really possible without modifying the Android source.

Answer (score -1):

There is a mod for this by, I think, TeamNocturnal...I have it working on Stock gb 2.3.5 for ZTE Merit.  Google search "swipe to clear notifications mod."